# change label to sum of datagridview column

Tags: datagridview

i am using C# visual studio
on main form its shows stock in datagridview1
i have datagridview1 with 5 column named Stock ID, Product Name, Product Type, Quantity, Total Price.
i want to show label name Lbl2 as sum of Total Price Column but i cant 
please help

```
 private void Lbl2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal TotalPrice = 0;

       foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
       {
           if (!row.IsNewRow && row.Cells["Total Price"].Value != null)
           {
               TotalPrice += (decimal)row.Cells["Total Price"].Value;
           }
       }

        Lbl2.Text = TotalPrice.ToString("N2");

    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to decimal this way:

```
TotalPrice += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Total Price"].Value);
```